# Syntax highlight for .ejs files in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, ejs

What is the best way to make vim highlight ejs (http://embeddedjs.com/) files?
Is it possible to set up html highlight for the file in general and javascript highlight to it's parts inside <% %>?
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 76):

Credits goes to @inkedmn just wanted to point out that html binding works way better, therefore put this in your ~/.vimrc file:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ejs set filetype=html
```

Answer (score 27):

Here's something I whipped up today (made some modifications to the eruby script). It requires the vim-javascript plugin to be installed.

https://github.com/briancollins/vim-jst

Comment: this is great, if you're like me you might just want to grab the: https://github.com/briancollins/vim-jst/blob/master/syntax/jst.vim file and include it in your $HOME/.vimrc file as:   au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ejs so $HOME/.vim/jst.vim

Comment: Nice. I just installed Vundle and then added `Bundle 'briancollins/vim-jst'` to my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Looks like the correct file association for `*.ejs` should be `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ejs      setf javascript.jsx`

Answer (score 8):

I've had the best results downloading [this syntax file](https://github.com/emilis/emilis-config/blob/master/.vim/syntax/ejs.vim) directly into ~/.vim/syntax

Comment: To use this file I had to add to my .vimrc:  
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ejs set filetype=ejs

Answer (score 3):

If you want them to be highlighted like regular .js files, you could add this to your .vimrc:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ejs set filetype=js
```

Not 100% sure that's what you're after - hope it helps.

Comment: Well, changing it a bit to au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ejs set filetype=javascript I could get the javascript hightlighting, however, it's not really readable... That would be really great to have html highlighted as html and javascript - as javascript (if it's possible).

Comment: Apparently you can use multiple filetype for a single buffer. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601403/multiple-file-types-in-vim/2604558#2604558

Comment: This works, thanks! However, is there probably a way to apply this command automatically to every file with .ejs extension?

Comment: Yes there is. Look at the example in this answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

For a solution that uses javascript and html syntax where appropriate (and not rely on any third-party javascript plugins) you need an ftdetect file which runs `autocmd` when files with the `.ejs` extension are loaded combined with an ejs syntax file.

If you're not concerned with how it works I've put a package together than you can grab from github [here](https://github.com/nikvdp/ejs-syntax). If using Vundle just add this to your .vimrc:

```
Bundle 'nikvdp/ejs-syntax'
```

To do it yourself, create two files in your `~/.vim` folder:

An ftdetect file: `~/.vim/ftdetect/ejs.vim`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ejs set filetype=ejs
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *._ejs set filetype=ejs

function! s:DetectEjs()
    if getline(1) =~ '^#!.*\<ejs\>'
        set filetype=ejs
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call s:DetectEjs()
```

And a syntax file (from user456584's answer) :  `~/.vim/syntax/ejs.vim`

```
runtime! syntax/html.vim
unlet b:current_syntax

" Include Java syntax
syn include @ejsJavaScript syntax/javascript.vim

syn region ejsScriptlet matchgroup=ejsTag start=/<%/  keepend end=/%>/ contains=@ejsJavaScript
syn region ejsExpr  matchgroup=ejsTag start=/<%=/ keepend end=/%>/ contains=@ejsJavaScript

" Redefine htmlTag so that it can contain jspExpr
syn clear htmlTag
syn region htmlTag start=+<[^/%]+ end=+>+ contains=htmlTagN,htmlString,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent,htmlCssDefinition,@htmlPreproc,@htmlArgCluster,ejsExpr,javaScript


" syn keyword ejsPrint contained print
syn match javaScriptType        /\<\zsvars\ze\./
syn match javaScriptSpecial     /\<\zsexports\ze\./
syn match javaScriptFunction    /\<\zsprint\ze(/
syn match javaScriptFunction    /\<\zsinclude\ze(/
syn match javaScriptFunction    /\<\zsincludeObject\ze(/
syn match javaScriptFunction    /\<\zsfetch\ze(/
syn match javaScriptFunction    /\<\zsfetchObject\ze(/

command -nargs=+ HiLink hi def link <args>
HiLink  ejsTag      htmlTag
delcommand HiLink

let b:current_syntax = "ejs"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cd /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax #maybe vim64 or other
cp html.vim ejs.vim
vim ejs.vim
```

you can just edit `html.vim`
but I suggest you not...
then find

```
syn region  javaScript start=+<script\_[^>]*>+ keepend end=+</script>+me=s-1` contains=@htmlJavaScript,htmlCssStyleComment,htmlScriptTag,@htmlPreproc
```

and write

```
  syn region  ejsScript start=+<%+ keepend end=+%>+ contains=@htmlJavaScript,htmlCssStyleComment,htmlScriptTag,@htmlPreproc
```

under that line.

find

```
  HtmlHiLink javaScript             Special
```

add

```
  HtmlHiLink ejsScript             Special
```

under it

add this line to your `~/.vimrc`

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ejs set filetype=ejs
```

now your ejs code will looks like js code...
or you just want it looks like something else?

replase

```
  HtmlHiLink ejsScript             Special
```

by (for example)

```
 hi def ejsScript                 term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
```

in fact, in this example,the two line can live together...

it makes your code lovely~

you can read [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-define) to help you with your vim-syntax