# Who have configured vim editor to highlight ejs syntax?

Tags: javascript, vim, ejs

Has anyone being able to highlight ejs syntax while using vim editor?

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137261/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+ejs

Comment: Yeah, I tried those, it didn't work for me