# How does Vim handle C++ as a superset of C?

Tags: vim

I was writing some filetype-specific vim scripts, `c.vim` and `cpp.vim`, when I noticed that for C++ files, both `c.vim` and `cpp.vim` were being executed.  This makes a lot of sense, since C++ is a superset of C.  But my question is this: where is the logic that makes this happen?

That is, is something baked in when vim is compiled that tells it that C++ files are also C files, or is there some file in the .vim directory that controls this behavior? Or something else entirely?

It might be interesting to note that checking the filetype vim has assigned to my C++ files (using `:set ft?`) returns `cpp`, not something like `c.cpp`, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601403/multiple-file-types-in-vim).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My `cpp.vim` file (under `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax)` has in it:

```
" Read the C syntax to start with
if version < 600
  so <sfile>:p:h/c.vim
else
  runtime! syntax/c.vim
  unlet b:current_syntax
endif
```

So it's reading the `c.vim` file.

Comment: Nice one.  I didn't even know about the existence of the `/usr/share/vim73` directory (although, should you care to know, mine is actually at `/usr/share/vim/vim73`).  Thanks!

Comment: @Riley... you found my typo, which I fixed. Mine's in the same location. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I'd *expect* that `cpp.vim` needs `c.vim` when using the `extern "C" {}` construct. It does not mean that C++ is seen as a superset of C from vim's eyes. But I did not read thoroughly the syntax file to be sure of that, because vim syntax files are painful to read ;-)

Otherwise, vim recognizes the file you're editing as a C++ file and loads its syntax through the [`ft`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html) mechanism, that only loads a set of syntax, plugins etc.. given the extension of the file (or the first chars, iinw).

HTH