# Change recognized filetype of a plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to use 'plasticboy/vim-markdown' and 'nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding.'  They require `filetype=mkd` and `filetype-markdown`, respectively.  Is there a typical way to tell a plugin to recognize a certain filetype?

I've tried changing references of `mkd` to `markdown` in the former and `markdown` to `mkd` in the latter but that hasn't had any effect.  As of now, I can only use one of the plugins because they require different filetypes.

Comment: You might try setting both filetypes at the same time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601403/multiple-file-types-in-vim. However this may behave poorly.

Comment: Thanks.  Working so far.  We'll see if any conflicts appear after continued use.

Comment: Doesn't `plasticboy/vim-markdown` support folding out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic names for the filetype plugins are (`:help ftplugin-name`):

```
ftplugin/<filetype>.vim
ftplugin/<filetype>_<name>.vim
ftplugin/<filetype>/<name>.vim
```

Therefore, you need to rename the file names themselves (possibly in addition to the contents in the file, though there shouldn't be that many). Since that makes upgrading more difficult, you can also write linker scripts, e.g. `~/.vim/ftplugin/mkd_fold.vim` which just contains the following command:

```
:runtime! ftplugin/markdown_fold.vim
```